# What is the default session expire time in Sinatra?

Tags: sinatra, rack

If I did not explicitly set the session expire time in Sinatra, then what would be the default expire time?

Answer (score 9):

The Sinatra session comes from Rack::Session; so out of the box it defaults to no expire.  To override you can do something like follows.

`set :sessions, :expire_after => 2592000`

Comment: I don't having this behaviour, if I don't set `expire_after` I get a _Session_ cookie :/

Comment: `Rack::Session::Cookie` is the default type of session used by Sinatra unless you override this behavior.  You can override with any other rack session middleware, for example `use Rack::Session::Pool, :expire_after => 2592000`